# How to Bind Two Controls in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to bind a control's value to another, like:

```xml
<Stepper x:Name="myValue"
         Maximum="1000"
         Minimum="0"
         Value="{Binding myValue,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric"
       Text="{Binding myValue}"
       TextColor="Black" />
```

Comment: You have not asked an actual question.

Comment: If you are having an issue with data binding try researching the Xamarin website here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/. There is usually some helpful examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `{x:Reference }` markup extension

```xml
<Stepper x:Name="myValue"
         Maximum="1000"
         Minimum="0"
         Value="{Binding myValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Entry Keyboard="Numeric"
       Text="{Binding Value, Source={x:Reference myValue}}"
       TextColor="Black" />
```